# Access subfolder's methods & classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails 4 app, I have a subfolder `logic` in my App folder, where I put classes/methods that don't belong to controllers or models.

However, when I try to access these methods from a controller, I get an unknown method error.

Here is a class in the `logic` folder:

```
class Analyze        
  def intent_determination(msg, context)
    keywords = [["categories", "category"], ["brands", "brand"], ["stock", "stocks"], ["info", "information"], ["no"], ["yes"]]
    tokenized_array = msg.split
    keywords.each {|array| context["intent"] = array.first if (tokenized_array & array).any? }
    context
  end

  def update_context(msg, session)
    session.update(context: intent_determination(msg, session.context))
    session.update(context: brand_determination(msg, session.context))
    session.update(context: style_determination(msg, session.context))
    session
  end
end
```

How can I access these methods in my controllers ? 
When I just execute `update_context(my_message, @session)`, as I said, I get an unknown method error.

Here is my App folder structure:

```
App 
 Assets
 Controllers
 Logic
   analyze.rb
 Helpers
 Mailers
 Models
 Views
```

EDIT:
I did add:
`config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/logic/**/')` to my application.rb file.

So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How add new folder with class in rails app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406383/how-add-new-folder-with-class-in-rails-app)

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth see my edit

Comment: `Analyze.new.update_context(...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `update_context` method is an instance method inside the class `Analyze`. To invoke it, you have to do `Analyze.new.update_context`.

The line `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/logic/**/')` you added tells Rails where to start looking for **classes** and **modules**. This means that Rails would be able to find your `Analyze` class just like that without you needing to do `require 'some/path'`.

Now, it seems like you probably want to have `update_context` be a class method rather than an instance method, so that you do not need to instantiate an `Analyze` object with `Analyze.new`. This is simple enough, just add `self.` before the method name:

```
class Analyze
  def self.update_context(msg, session)
  end
end
```

`Analyze` could also be a **module** in that case instead of a **class**, since an "instance" of it doesn't really seem to represent anything concrete.

Either as class or module, when defining the method as `def self.update_context` you'll be able to do `Analyze.update_context(...)` from anywhere in your app.

If you're looking for these helper methods to be used inside your views, consider defining `update_context` as a method inside `app/helpers/application.helper.rb`. Simply define it as you did (without the `self.`) and you'll be able to call it from any view and without any "prefix" (i.e. you'll be able to simply do `update_context` instead of `Analyze.update_context`). Rails also allows you to call such helpers from controllers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613223/where-to-put-ruby-helper-methods-for-rails-controllers)) and models (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489641/using-helpers-in-model-how-do-i-include-helper-dependencies)), although it would be wise to keep separation of concerns in mind (view logic stays in view helpers, persistency logic and access to data in models, and action-specific business-logic in controllers) rather than "including everything into everything" because it seems convenient.